# vertical text for abline in xts

Tags: r, text, plot, xts

I am looking for a way to put (possibly vertical) text on a abline in xts, but it seems I can't define where to put the text (however, I can define the abline):

```
require(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix, descr='my new xts object')


for (i in 1:dim(sample.xts)[2]){
  cat(paste("\n",i))
  plot((tail(sample.xts[,i],10)), main=paste("column" ,i))
  print(lines(x = tail(sample.xts[,i],10), col = "darkgreen", lty=2, on=1))
  abline(v=.index(last(sample.xts[-dim(sample.xts)[1],])), col="red",lty=3)
  # text( here possibly some vertical text)
}
```

edited: the code is reproducible now.
I need a way to place the text to the abline with the time index, not with a number (or to find out the correct number)
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of xts are you using?

Comment: I use version 0.9.874 but I could update to the latest if it helps.

Comment: On WIndos it is 0.9-7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xts version on CRAN is currently 0.9-7.  Using that version, you need to use `text()` and the `srt` parameter to add and rotate text.  If you're having trouble defining the location, you can use your mouse with the `locator()` function to find the coordinates interactively.

```
# Using xts 0.9-7
require(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
x <- tail(as.xts(sample_matrix, dateFormat = "Date"), 10)[,1]

plot(x)
lines(x, col = "darkgreen", lty=2)
v <- last(.index(x)[-nrow(x)])
abline(v = v, col = "red", lty = 3)
text(v, max(x), "label", pos = 2, srt = 90)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joshua! For others: the lower label is:     text(v, min(tail(x,10)), "xxx", pos = 3, srt = 90)

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is not reproducible I am using a built in data set. For a 90 degrees rotation you can use the following:

```
attach(mtcars)
plot(mpg ~ hp)
abline(v = 170)
text(x = 180, y = 25, label = "Your text here!", srt = 90)
```